# Es posible saber si hubo un error en el envío de un correo con ActionMailer en Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Justo lo que pregunto en el título.  Es posible saber si hubo un error en el envío de un correo con ActionMailer en Ruby On Rails?

Gracias.

Comment: Se deben mostrar en los logs, si no es así, posiblemente tengas que actualizar tu `development.rb` con `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nunca encontré una manera para saber si realmente el correo se envió exitosamente.

Para solucionar el tema, creé un segundo hilo en la aplicación donde utilizo la clase Net::IMAP, con la que me conecto al servidor de GMail saliente y reviso si el correo realmente fue enviado.  Para eso, busco en la bandeja de salida un correo con el "asunto" indicado que identifica al correo que estoy buscando.

```
@imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com', 993, usessl = true, certs = nil, verify = false)
@imap.authenticate('PLAIN', @username, @password)
    
@imap.examine('[Gmail]/Enviados')
encontrado = @imap.uid_search( ["SUBJECT", "LO QUE VOY A BUSCAR EN EL ASUNTO PARA ENCONTRAR EL CORREO ENVIADO"] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Revisa la configuración que tengas en el archivo de `environments/development.rb` y asegúrate de que tenga lo siguiente

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

Comment: Esto no funcionó para mí.